# How do I get a random number/letter generator to generate 3 Letters then 6 Numbers? in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

```
 public string RandomGenerator()
    {
        var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
        var random = new Random();
        var result = new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 9).Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
        txtReference.Text = result;

        return result;

    }
```

I have this code, but I want it so it is specifically 3 letters at the beginning then 6 numbers.

Comment: Implementation of this operation should be made carefully if you want a uniform distribution.  It is not a bad idea to look at time-proven implementations, e. g. random.sample from Python ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample), [implementation](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/random.py)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building on what you've already done, just generate a string of the random characters, then a string of the random numbers and just concatenate the two:

```
public string RandomGenerator()
    {
        var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        var numbers= "0123456789";
        var random = new Random();

        var letterResult = new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 3).Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());    
        var numberResult = new string(Enumerable.Repeat(number, 6).Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());

        txtReference.Text = letterResult + numberResults;

        return result;

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the same approach you can try like this :

```
 public string RandomGenerator()
        {     
                var chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
                var allNumbers = "0123456789";
                var random = new Random();
                var letters = new string(
                                Enumerable.Repeat(chars, 3)
                                .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)])
                                .ToArray());


                var numbers = new string(
                                Enumerable.Repeat(allNumbers, 6)
                                .Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)])
                                .ToArray());

                var result = letters + numbers;

                txtReference.Text = result;

                return result;
    }
```

Comment: You have two vars called numbers :D